# When was the first time Iron Man used an AI assisted suit?

Tags: marvel, iron-man

In the MCU Iron Man uses JARVIS as his AI assistance but in the comics when was the first time the concept of something like an AI assistance was used for assisting him and controlling the suit? What was the name of that AI assistance?

Comment: By AI assistance do you mean an AI assisted suit as indicated by your title? If so you might want to edit the body to make that clearer because currently there is some ambiguity.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot I want to ask something like JARVIS which made the suits work on voice commands

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer relates directly to Iron Man as opposed to the wider Marvel 616 Universe (main comics continuity).

What is considered AI maybe debatable, but the first instance of Iron Man using a personal AI assistant, with a name that you could have a conversation with, was H.O.M.E.R. - *Heuristically Operative Matrix Emulation Rostrum*.

First appeared in Iron Man issue 298 in 1993 according to [marvel.fandom.com](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Heuristically_Operative_Matrix_Emulation_Rostrum_(Earth-616))

Comment: Does HOMER actually assist with the suits though? He doesn’t in the issue you link as far as I can tell.

Comment: The question asked about AI assistants, as opposed to AI assistants that help out with the suits operations. I'm fairly sure the suits had voice commands prior to this (hence the comment about what is AI), but I need to find a cite for that. I'm also sure HOMER could control the suits without a human pilot, but I need to find a cite for that too.

Comment: The title specifically states “AI assisted suit” which HOMER isn’t, at least initially anyway.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - point taken

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot K Mo may be right. Quoting what I found on the wiki link of H.O.M.E.R: " *He [HOMER] operates the computer system at his home, Stark industries* and **the Iron Man armors**.

Comment: @Shreedhar there’s a few distinctions here. Firstly, as far as I can tell HoMER doesn’t do that in the mentioned issue, though I only skimmed it. Secondly, some of the AIs operate the suits on their own without Stark which isn’t what the question is about.